Two parallel programs of work hitting a single production environment
We have two programs of work targeting the same production environment. For convenience, and to show “progress” the programs have split their SIT environments.
The API team has chosen to not split its codebases, is running a single team for both environments and is using trunk-based approach with single main branch and feature flags, which is in line with the organization’s documented branching strategy.
Other teams have chosen to split their teams for convenience and create long-running branches for each program of work, and defer the merge to later. The data team is one of these.
It’s resulted in a number of feature flags at the API level in SIT, not only for sequential release but to accommodate the parallel long-lived branches in other layers. The data layer teams for each program are introducing incompatible data types and are missing columns, in each of the long-lived program branches.
The data layer is being built by a vendor and they’ve enlisted the program managers (who want to show “progress” on their streams of work) and the IT leadership, although initially supportive of a trunk based approach, now view it as a “religious debate”, despite the shims being introduced in the form of feature flags, and have pushed the API team to split their codebase into long-running branches and to merge later.
What’s the correct approach here? Should the API team split their code into separate long-lived branches and defer the merge to later?

can you clarify a bit, is the integration team one of the two teams? what are both environments? draw us a diagram

There are multiple layers, each being built by a separate team. The integration layer is a single team. The data layer, and others, to reduce the overhead of dealing with separate development programs, backlogs etc split. They also split their codebases.
There’s a lack of strong cross-cutting technical leadership so each team pretty much operates as it wants, with non-technical program managers and release managers for each program calling the shots.

is the is integration team doing one of the layers, or integrating all the other work somehow?

They’re building an APi. I’ll rename it.

are the other teams pushing branch builds to test?

There are two “SIT” environments, one for each program. That’s meant to be the first point of integration. For lower environments, the data team is meant to provide a schema to the API team, but it turns out that is actually from just one of the long-lived branches.

Just to clarify, SIT means System Integration Testing, right?

yes SIT is the first integration environment

I think i follow your meaning? Let me boil it down and you can say if I'm wrong
You have ONE feature that spans TWO teams

Team Database
Has made a long lived feature branch and wants to (integration) test it before merging to main

Team API
Is using trunk based development and wants to push every small change to main as it happens


Both teams want to test the new feature which requires the API to link to a build made from the database long lived feature branch.
The API team need their changes to work with both the feature branch version of the DB and the main version  of the DB. So they introduced a feature toggle
In theory this is fine, but obviously is means maintaining a code base that works with both the feature on and off for an extended period of time. This will make things harder for the API team while its on going. Presumably they are complaining and want the DB team to finish quicker.
The DB team presumably reply saying the problem is this crazy new trunk based development and the API team should just make a feature branch like they did.
For $64m Who is right??!?
I am not a fan of trunk based development. But, really it's just the same as short lived feature branches.
The solution is to split the work into smaller chunks so that the DB team is able to merge in completed parts of the work in short iterations. This will allow the API team to take out their toggles more frequently, or not have to use them at all.
Trunk development might be a religious debate, but Everyone agrees that long lived feature branches are bad.

Given politics there is another solution which I would not usually recommend.
The DB layer could abstract the schema with sprocs and views. This puts the burden on the DB team to make a backwards/(forwards?) compatible interface

Everyone except IT leadership and the two program managers think that long-lived feature branches are bad, along with the vendor building the Data layer. They also don’t want to merge early because it makes their program look bad because it slows down “delivery” to SIT

lol there is prob a dilbert comic for that

The trouble with the long live API branch in this case I think is that basically you are admitting that the change will never happen, kicking the problems down the road and leaving the door open to just not ever merging. This might be an attractive option politically but its not great for the people involved. The project should probably be reset and rethought

The two codebases will have to merge; there’s no way it won’t happen. My guess is that the vendor team that is doing the first db codeset into production wants to walk away and leave the merge to the other db team (ironically from the same vendor) to do.

@NMrt "will have to merge" not if the company goes under before it does
